# How to make the listValue in Struts2 radio tag a hyperlink?

Tags: struts2

I know how to use `<s:iterator>` to make a list of hyperlinks with the following code:

```
    <s:iterator value="imagesList">
      <s:url var="linkReport" action="view" namespace="/">
        <s:param name="documentId" value="%{documentId}"></s:param>
      </s:url>
      <s:a href="%{linkReport}" target="_blank"><s:property value="%{documentName}"/></s:a><br>
   </s:iterator>
```

I know how to use `<s:iterator>` with the `<s:radio>` tag to make a vertical list of radio buttons as follows:

```
    <s:iterator value="imagesList">
       <s:radio name="mainId" listValue="documentName" list="{myObject}" listKey="documentId" ></s:radio><br>
    </s:iterator>
```

What I would like to do is combine the two pieces of code and make the `listValue` in the `<s:radio>` tab into the hyperlinks in the first piece of code.  The following doesn't work but it shows what I want to do.

```
    <s:iterator value="imagesList">
        <s:radio name="mainId" listValue="<s:a href="%{linkReport}" target="_blank"><s:property value="%{documentName}"/></s:a>" list="{myObject}" listKey="documentId" ></s:radio><br>
    </s:iterator>
```

Comment: IMO the list generation should be done outside of the view layer. Create the list of URLs and names in the action and expose only that to the view layer.

Comment: Labels should stay as labels, don't turn them into hyperlinks.